# Why can I not delete my answer after someone accepts it?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

I posted an answer in response to [What will happen if I do not attack Sephiroth on the final battle?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/92663/what-will-happen-if-i-do-not-attack-sephiroth-on-the-final-battle/92665#comment143873_92665)

There is now an outstanding post that proves my answer is incorrect. I tried to delete my answer and am greeted with "You cannot delete this accepted answer".

[image]

Now what is the point of this feature, as this is now confusing to anyone who reads that page? The only other option I can see is to edit my answer saying this is incorrect please ignore, or copying the correct answer from the other post.

What is the best action for me to take in this situation?

Comment: You could unaccept it, then delete it.

Comment: @jeffreylin_ It was not his question; it was his answer that was accepted.

Comment: @fbueckert Oops, must have misread that.

Answer (score 2):

**The general answer**
Your only option is to flag it for mod attention and explain the situation -- if everything checks out, a mod can delete for you.
You cannot remove it yourself if accepted, and this is [by-design across the entire network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14932/allow-author-of-accepted-answer-to-delete-it-in-certain-circumstances).

**In this case**
This meta post already brought it to our attention, but feel free to flag it anyway to add it to our queue.

Comment: Is there any reason why this occurs. Is there any downside that I am not seeing?

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14932/allow-author-of-accepted-answer-to-delete-it-in-certain-circumstances and every linked question from there, like this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/allow-accepted-answer-recipient-to-give-it-away

Comment: Doesn't unaccepting it work?

Comment: @kotekzot he wrote the answer, accepting and unaccepting is an ability of the question asker

Comment: Oh, I see. For some reason I thought it was a self-answer.